# Estimote Ibeacon couldnt detect with Mac late 2011

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, proximity, estimote

I am Ahmet. I have been trying to solve a problem for 3 days, that I have about communicating with Estimote beacon first time. (I am quite new on beacons), I have read a lot of articles and looked for many example codes. Even tried the Estimote example app (provided in the Estimote SDK file). Some how I could not find the beacons through the code that I have written and example code (app) in the SDK file. But estimote application on the app store works fine.

I am using MacBookPro late 2011 version.

If you help me about this, I would appreciated that. My purpose is to communicate first, then the rest will come. I cannot go out from the house, so I have written the code in that way.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
//MainViewController.h
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>


@property(nonatomic, strong)CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;

@property(nonatomic, strong)CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end





@implementation MainViewController

(void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self initRegion];

    [self locationManager:self.locationManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion]; 

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    NSLog(@"did start monitoring");

    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

}

-(void)initRegion

{

    NSLog(@"Init Region");

    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"]; 

    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"identifier"] ;

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];

}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region

{

    NSLog(@"Did enter region"); // never called

    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region

{

    NSLog(@"Did exit region"); // never called

    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    NSLog(@"NO Beacon Found...");

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region

{

    NSLog(@"did range Beacons");

    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc]init];

    beacon = [beacons lastObject];



    NSLog(@"BEACON FOUND");

    NSLog(@"Proximity UUID: %@",beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString);

    NSLog(@"MAJOR ID: %@", beacon.major);

    NSLog(@"MINOR ID: %@", beacon.minor);

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to *MacTracker*, your MacBookPro is not compatible.

Apple put a Bluetooth Low-Energy chip in its MacBook Pro starting with the Mid 2012.

Since iBeacon use in reality BLE (which is hidden, at least in the iOS part: CLBeacon vs CoreBluetooth), you won't detect iBeacon with your MBP, except if you may have a special BLE chip (extern, as some USB one we can find in the market).

To verify if you laptop is BLE compatible, I'd suggest you read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/702670/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-has-bluetooth-4-0-low-energy) on SuperUser.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much :) i have red in a article and it was saying that mac late 2011 supports.
Now i m sure it doesnt.
Thank you.

Comment: In 2011, it was the MBA that got that BLE chip. If the anwser is correct, could you validate it?